# Example Java EE web service with DTO and DAO

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am looking for an example of a J2EE web service that implements a DTO layer and a DAO layer. I'm familiar with the concepts involved, but am struggling to put the project together in a way that makes sense. Currently I have:

- A Web Service (WAR) project that holds the web resources and has a
  reference to the Remote project.
- The Remote (JAR) project that has the remote interfaces to the EJBs
- EJB (JAR) project that has the implementation of the EJBs as well as the DAO objects - entities and helper DAO classes. And mapper classes to map between DAO and DTO. This references the Remote project.

The EJBs do the mapping from DAO to DTO and return the DTO to the Web Service classes.

I've since been considering moving the mapper classes into the Web Service project as that seems to a good practice - it frees up the EJBs to act on the business objects and not on the DTO.

Examples of the classes are below:

`PersonResource` class in Web Service project:

```
@Path("/person")
@Stateless
public class PersonResource {
    @EJB
    private IPersonManagerRemote ejb;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/{id}")
    public PersonDTO get(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return ejb.get(id);
    }
```

`IPersonManagerRemote` interface in Remote project:

```
@Remote
public interface IPersonManagerRemote  {
    public PersonDTO get(long id);
}
```

`PersonManager` implementation in the EJB project:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class PersonManager implements IPersonManagerRemote {
    @Inject
    private IPersonDAO dao;

    @Override
    public PersonDTO get(Long id) {
        return PersonMapper.getInstance().map(dao.get(id));
    }
```

`PersonMapper` singleton class in EJB project:

```
public class PersonMapper {
    // Singleton creation code...

    public PersonDTO map(Person dao) {
         //Mapping code here to copy fields
    }
}
```

I have excluded the `IPersonDao` interface and it's implementation `PersonDao` as they are pretty standard.

I tried to move the call to the mapper to the web resource, but then I need a reference to the EJB project (for the DAO objects) in both the web project and the remote project, which causes a circular reference because the EJB project references the Remote project.

Should my EJB classes be returning DTO or DAO objects and if DAO then where should the mapping code reside?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to move dao and mapping code up to the webapp. Separation of concerns. The webapp should only need to know about the service api, whichof the dto's are part.

Comment: Not quite what I meant. Should the service facade be aware of the DAO and should the mapping between DAO and DTO happen there or at a lower level? I agree the presentation layer shouldn't know about the DAO.

Comment: Yes, I certainly hope your web-service, where you consider to call dao and mapping, presumably in PersonResource, is not in the presentation layer :) What do you expect to achieve by doing that?